# Importing several txt files in R

Tags: r, import, filenames

I would like to import several ".txt" file in R and add a new "ID" column with the file name in it.
I found something like that that works to import all the txt files but I don't have my "ID" column.

```
listfile <- list.files("C:/Users/........",pattern = "txt",full.names = T, recursive = TRUE)

for (i in 1:length(listfile)){
  if(i==1){
    assign(paste0("Data"), read.table(listfile[i],header = TRUE, sep = ",", skipNul = TRUE))
  }
}

rm(list = ls(pattern = "list.+?"))
```

All the files name have this format: "XXX-M_N6 2021-04-16.txt" with different letter instead of "XXX" and other date as well.
Any idea how to do that?
Thanks!

Comment: Do you want all the files ending up in a single dataframe (let's say `Data`) with an `ID` column indicating the origin file?

Comment: Yes that's what I'd like to have.

Answer (score 1):

```r
library(purrr)


purrr::map_dfr(listfile, 
               ~{cbind(read.table(.x, header = TRUE, sep = ",", skipNul = TRUE),
                       ID = .x)})
```

Comment: There is an error message that I don't understand:    Error in as_mapper(.f, ...) : 
  l'argument ".f" est manquant, avec aucune valeur par défaut      I should add your code after mine right?

Comment: You probably need to upgrade  R  to 4.1, I edited the code so that it should work with older versions. Let me know

Comment: Yes it works! There is the whole path in the ID column instead of just the file name, but I can select only what I need from that so that's fine! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Using R base, you can try something like:

```
path_arqs = dir() # accept that your csvs files are the same
df = do.call(rbind, lapply(path_arqs, read.csv))
```